# lab and laboratory

Tags: formality, abbreviations

Can **lab** be used not as a shorthand or abbreviation for **laboratory**? There are many courses titled such as `Chemistry Lab` and `Physics Lab` and I somewhat feel like `lab` is more like a complete word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Lab* can be considered a proper word in its own right, fully substitutable in all situations where *laboratory* might be used.  It has similar status to other shortened words like *tarp* and *auto*.

Actually, I would argue that the inverse substitution cannot always be done for some extended uses of *lab* that refer more to the scientific work that is done inside an experimental facility than to the facility itself.  Consider:

- A specific experiment that is done, often as an assignment in a course, is called a *lab*.  For example:

  > The TA deducted 5 points from my score on Lab #3 because I failed to explain all the sources of experimental error in my report.

  To my ears, calling that assignment "Laboratory #3" would sound slightly weird, because no student talks that way.
- A white garment worn by chemists to protect their clothes is called a *lab coat*.  [*Laboratory coat* has been falling out of favor in comparison to *lab coat* quite strongly since about 1970,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laboratory+coat%2C+lab+coat%2C+labcoat&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) more so than [*laboratory* vs. *lab*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laboratory%2C+lab&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).   Similarly, a rat that biologists experiment on is usually called a *lab rat*.  [*Laboratory rat* has been slowly falling out of favor since 1980](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laboratory+rat%2Clab+rat&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), though for now either term is acceptable.

  Why is *lab* being increasingly preferred in *lab coat* and *lab rat*?  My guess is that people think of these things as unitary concepts, and are starting to form them as one word mentally (though not yet writing them as a compound word).  The linguist John McWhorter has noticed a [phenomenon he calls "the backshift"](https://shelf-awareness.com/readers-issue.html?issue=540#m9439), where people increasingly start to stress the first syllable of a unitary concept ("HOT dog", "SUpermarket", "GRIDlock") instead of stressing the two original words equally.  The word *laboratory* is just too long and cumbersome to facilitate this backshift, I think?

---

As contrasting example of the shortening process, *fridge* is pretty close to being an acceptable full replacement for *refrigerator*, though for now it is still considered slightly informal.  (If you buy a fridge, the owner's manual will still call it a *refrigerator*.)

Comment: Yes. "Lab" started out as an informal, short word for "laboratory", but it is so commonly used today that even in formal writing, I don't think it would be considered out of place.

Answer (score 0):

With various *possible* meanings, the abbreviation *Lab* is also used for Laboratory. [Abbreviations.com](http://www.abbreviations.com/LAB) has an entry for that. Also, note that there are other meanings for what *Lab* is used.

Said that, it can be used for Physics/Chemistry Lab. You have to change your feelings, *lab* is not a complete word but an abbreviation!

I too wondered this when heard about [*cath-lab*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cath_lab)